# writing a web.config for a php REST API

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis

For a university project, I have written a REST api using php on my development server (localhost). I had to edit the .htaccess for it to work. The contents are here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* api.php/$0 [L]
```

But the deployment server is IIS and I have no idea how to configure the webconfig file. I have tried to read up on it, but I am not sure how to go about it.

The server is on the university network and there is no chance of any changes to the main configuration of the server being made, or additional libraries being installed.

If it can't be done simply then I do have access to my own hosted Apache server which I can run it from.

I was wondering if anyone would be able to convert the above into what I need for IIS?

EDIT: I spent some time reading more about the rewrite, which according to my module leader is enabled on the server. i have attempted to write the rules into the web.config and this is what i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>

  </system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Rewrite to server.php">
        <match url="^([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+).*" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</configuration>
```

but it isnt working.

Thanks

Comment: `.htaccess` is for Apache, `web.config` is for IIS. Are you mixing the two?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `web.config`.  That is only for .Net projects.  You need to use the IIS equivalent to apache's `mod_rewrite`.  Here is an article that should help configure rewrite rules on IIS.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: I have read that, and have tried a test to see if it will work. according to there, there will be a web.config see above for my test